# Relay Mutation with serverside validation

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I am trying to code a relay mutation that will allow server side validation. Such as a record with that name already exists.

Below is my GraphQL mutation.

```
/* @flow weak */
import {mutationWithClientMutationId,offsetToCursor} from "graphql-relay";
import {GraphQLString, GraphQLList, GraphQLNonNull} from "graphql";
import NominationConnection from '../NominationsConnection';
import ViewerType from '../../../types/ViewerType';
import Helper from '../../../helper/helper';
import Nomination from '../../../model/Nomination';


const mongo = require('mongodb');

/**
 * mutationWithClientMutationId()
 *
 * This helper function helps us create Relay-compliant GraphQL mutations it takes an object with the following params
 * { name: "", inputField: { }, outputFields: {},  mutateAndGetPayload: function({}) }
 *
 */
export default mutationWithClientMutationId({

  // Name of the Mutation
  name: "Nomination_Add",

  // Describes the fields that should be used when invoking the mutation
  inputFields: {
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    description: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
    }

  },

  // response that will be sent back when the mutation is complete
  outputFields: {
    NominationsEdge: {
      type: NominationConnection.edgeType,
      resolve: ( {local_id}, { ...args }, context, { rootValue: objectManager } ) =>
      {
        //RT: local_id is the object that was inserted into DB.;
        let nomination = local_id[0];
        console.log("nomination: ", nomination);
        if(nomination.Errors.length > 0){

          return objectManager.getListBy('Nomination', nomination, {}, {})
              .then((arr) => {

                return ( {
                  cursor: null,
                  node: nomination,
                } )
              })
        }else {

          let an_Object;
          return objectManager.getOneByParam('Nomination', nomination, {_id: nomination.id})
              .then((retrieved_Object) => {


                an_Object = retrieved_Object;

              })

              .then(() => objectManager.getListBy('Nomination', an_Object, {}, {}, objectManager.getViewerUserId()))
              .then((arr) => {


                return ( {
                  cursor: Helper.cursorForObjectInConnection(arr, an_Object, "id"),
                  node: an_Object,
                } )
              })
              ;
        }
      }
    },

    Viewer: {
      type: ViewerType,
      resolve: (parent, args, context, {rootValue: objectManager}) => objectManager.getOneById('User', objectManager.getViewerUserId())
    }
  },

  mutateAndGetPayload: ({name, description, books}, context, {rootValue: objectManager}) => {
    if(!books){
      books = [];
    }

    return objectManager.add('Nomination', {
      name,
      description,
      books
    }, {name: name}).then((local_id) => ( {local_id} ));
  }
});
```

Below is my relay mutation.

```
/* @flow weak */

import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class Nomination_addMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  // static fragments = {
  //   Viewer: () => Relay.QL`
  //     fragment on Viewer {
  //       id,
  //     }
  //   `,
  // };
  getMutation() {

    return Relay.QL`mutation{Nomination_Add}`;
  }
  getFatQuery() {


    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on Nomination_AddPayload {
      NominationsEdge,
        Viewer {
         Nominations(first:500){
         edges{
          node{
             id,
            Name,
            Description
            }
          }
         }
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {

    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'Viewer',
      parentID: this.props.Viewer.id,
      connectionName: 'Nominations',
      edgeName: 'NominationsEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: {
        // When the ships connection is not under the influence
        // of any call, append the ship to the end of the connection
        '': 'append',
        // Prepend the ship, wherever the connection is sorted by age
       // 'orderby(newest)': 'prepend',
      },
    }];
  }
  getVariables() {

    return {

      name: this.props.name,
      description: this.props.description,
      books: this.props.books,
    };
  }
  getOptimisticResponse() {


    return {
      Nomination: {

        name: this.props.name,
        description: this.props.description,
        books: this.props.books,

    },
      Viewer: {
      id: this.props.Viewer.id,
    },
    };
  }
}
```

Here is how i call on it.

```
 Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
        new Nomination_Add( {name: fields.name , description: fields.desc ,Viewer:this.props.Viewer}),
          {
            onSuccess: response => {
             console.log(response);
              console.log(response.Nomination_Add);
            },
          }
      );
```

My response object only has the Viewer.id and clientmuationID nothing else. When i call on this mutation via graphql it looks like this.

```
mutation{
  Nomination_Add(input:{name:"test", description:"test", clientMutationId:"2"}){
  NominationsEdge{
    node{
      Name,
      Description,
    Errors {
      Message
    }
      Books{
        Title
      }
    }
  }
  }

}
```

with a response of this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "Nomination_Add": {
      "NominationsEdge": {
        "node": {
          "Name": "test",
          "Description": "test",
          "Errors": [
            {
              "Message": "Nomination Already Exists"
            }
          ],
          "Books": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i get my server validation error messages back to the client via relay to write logic against?

also tried this as my fat query

```
 return Relay.QL`
      fragment on Nomination_AddPayload {
      NominationsEdge {
        node{
            Errors {
              Message
            }
          }
        },
        Viewer {
         Nominations(first:500){
         edges{
          node{
             id,
            Name,
            Description
            }
          }
         }
        }
      }
    `;
```

response looks like this:

```
{,…}
data
:
{Nomination_Add: {clientMutationId: "0", Viewer: {id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}}}
Nomination_Add
:
{clientMutationId: "0", Viewer: {id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}}
Viewer
:
{id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
id
:
"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
clientMutationId
:
"0"
```

Comment: `Viewer: {id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}` <-- can you check if you assigned `id` to your viewer object (not the GraphQL type, but the object with which the GraphQL type is associated)?

Comment: Yes, we are currently assigning that while the app is still being built.

Comment: What do you get when you run the following query in graphiql interface?
    `query xyz {
        Viewer {
            id, 
            Nominations(first:1){
                edges{
                    node{
                        id,
                        Name,
                        Description
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You're not receiving server-side validation error messages because you haven't told Relay that you want them. Take a look at your GraphiQL mutation and your relay mutation's fat query. You have included `Errors` in the former, but not in the latter.

Include `Errors` in your relay mutation's (`Nomination_addMutation`) fat query like below:

```
fragment on Nomination_AddPayload {
  NominationsEdge {
      node {
        Errors {
          Message
        }
      }
  },
  Viewer {
    Nominations(first:500){
      edges{
        node{
          id,
          Name,
          Description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had tried as well. The problem I run into is still that same.   return Relay.QL`
      `fragment on Nomination_AddPayload {
      NominationsEdge {
        node{
            Errors {
              Message
            }
          }
        },
        Viewer {
         Nominations(first:500){
         edges{
          node{
             id,
            Name,
            Description
            }
          }
         }
        }
      }
    `;` returns the same response

Comment: You put `Errors` field inside `node` field inside `NominationsEdge`. That's why you didn't get the expected response. In my answer, `Errors` field is directly inside `NominationsEdge`.

Comment: Thanks for your help again! I did that on purpose because that is how my schema is defined.  Errors lives on nominationType. Should it be moved?

Comment: You're right. Sorry I didn't realize that `Errors` is inside `node`. Please take care of code formatting in future.

Answer (score 0):

I can throw a error on mutateAndGetPayload:  This will be shipped as a error message to the onFailure callback of the mutation with the error message being what I throw.

```
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({name, description, books}, context, {rootValue: objectManager}) => {
    if(!books){
      books = [];
    }

    return objectManager.add('Nomination', {
      name,
      description,
      books
    }, {name: name}).then((nominations) => {

      //RT: readability
    let nomination = nominations[0];

      //RT: if Mongo id is not assigned.
      // No records where created.
         if(nomination.id == null)
          throw nomination.Errors[0].Message;

      return ( {nomination}

      )});
  }
```

This does not seem like the correct way to do this. Has anyone seen any better examples?

Edit: Cleaned up code and decided to do this based off of theses examples. Doesn't seem right.

https://medium.com/@fcpgate/i-think-what-eslam-mentioned-is-more-on-the-right-track-cdd07519bf97#.na73ulbxj (Read comments.)

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-store.html

http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/37044914/how-to-tackle-server-side-input-validation-using-relay?rq=1

https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/696

Comment: By throwing error, you can receive at most one validation error on the client-side. This is the only limitation as I see.

Comment: It seems you initially (in your queston)  kind of followed the same approach as in [this article](https://medium.com/@tarkus/validation-and-user-errors-in-graphql-mutations-39ca79cd00bf#.e4p4rfw8x), which is actually a very good approach.

Comment: Yes,  I enjoyed that article and my graphql mutations work exactly like that. It is getting relay to use the mutations the way i do, is my problem!

Comment: @AhmadFerdous what is your opinion of the comments on the post you linked?

Comment: I do not agree with those. For instance, "Otherwise, relay will think your mutation is successful and update local store to reflect that." When the intended field in mutation's response is `null` (e.g., user), there's nothing to update.